# How to group by records according to date in Tsql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that daily stores In_time and Out_Time of each employees. I want to calculate working hours of each employees on weekly basis or maybe per month? How do i do that?

Table structure:

```
               **Empid** :    1     ;    2     ;  3
               **Pdate** : 7 aug 15 ; 8 aug 15 ; 9 aug 15
               **P_In**  : 8:48:21  ; 8:50:10  ; 8:37:00
               **P_Out** : 15:07:21  ; 16:45:18  ; 16:47:10
```

and so on for the complete year.
*Empid* - **varchar**
*Pdate, P_In, P-Out* -  **datetime**

Now i want to *calculate total working hours* of each employees **per week**, per month or between given range of dates.
Please someone help how to apply '*group by*' in such scenario.

**What i did:**
There is seperate column which stores the difference between Pin and Pout; say its termed Workhrs.
So, Workhrs = Pout - Pin

*SELECT emp_name, emp_id, minutes_worked = SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', WorkHRs))  from dailydata group by Emp_Name,Emp_ID*

The above query will give me data of total minutes worked by each employee. However i want workhrs per week and per month. How do i do that?

Comment: where is the query you tried. Show some efforts

Comment: Don't store date and time in two different columns, have one timestamp column instead. Will be much easier that way.

Comment: How come the employees leave before they arrive?

Comment: Even if i remove Pdate column,  i still have two columns with Pin and Pout.

Comment: data type of `[P_In], [P_Out]` `varchar or time`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Week:

```
select 
  Empid, 
  datepart(ww, Pdate) per_week, 
  sum(DATEDIFF(mi, P_In, P_Out))/60.0 total_time
from employees
--where Pdate betweek start_date and end_date
group by Empid, datepart(ww, Pdate)
order by Empid
```

Per Month:

```
select 
  Empid, 
  datepart(mm, Pdate) per_month, 
  sum(DATEDIFF(mi, P_In, P_Out))/60.0 total_time
from employees
--where Pdate betweek start_date and end_date
group by Empid, datepart(mm, Pdate)
order by Empid
```

If you want to have data between two dates uncomment the where clause and substitute dates for `start_date and end_date`

Here its assumed that the datatype of `[P_In], [P_Out]` is time datatype, If it is `varchar` then use `cast`;  `cast(P_In as date)` :

Demo: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71dbf/2)

Comment: can we apply where clause in the above query, like for particular employee?

Comment: Yes... `where Empid = 1` if you alredy have a where clause then `and Empid = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Not sure.. Verify with your data and change as you like

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),EMPID INT, PDATE DATETIME,PIN DATETIME,POUT DATETIME ) 

INSERT INTO #TEMP (EMPID , PDATE ,PIN ,POUT )VALUES(1,'2015-09-10 00:00:00','2015-09-10 08:10:00','2015-09-10 16:10:00')
INSERT INTO #TEMP (EMPID , PDATE ,PIN ,POUT )VALUES(2,'2015-09-10 00:00:00','2015-09-10 08:05:00','2015-09-10 16:25:00')
INSERT INTO #TEMP (EMPID , PDATE ,PIN ,POUT )VALUES(3,'2015-09-10 00:00:00','2015-09-10 08:01:00','2015-09-10 16:03:00')
INSERT INTO #TEMP (EMPID , PDATE ,PIN ,POUT )VALUES(1,'2015-09-11 00:00:00','2015-09-11 08:20:00','2015-09-11 16:10:00')
INSERT INTO #TEMP (EMPID , PDATE ,PIN ,POUT )VALUES(2,'2015-09-11 00:00:00','2015-09-11 08:12:00','2015-09-11 16:14:00')
INSERT INTO #TEMP (EMPID , PDATE ,PIN ,POUT )VALUES(3,'2015-09-11 00:00:00','2015-09-11 08:10:00','2015-09-11 16:10:00')
INSERT INTO #TEMP (EMPID , PDATE ,PIN ,POUT )VALUES(1,'2015-09-12 00:00:00','2015-09-12 08:00:00','2015-09-12 16:00:00')

SELECT EMPID,CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(n,PIN,POUT))/60 AS VARCHAR)+':'+CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(n,PIN,POUT))%60 AS VARCHAR) AS [HH:MM] FROM  #TEMP WHERE PDATE BETWEEN '2015-09-10 00:00:00' AND '2015-09-12 00:00:00' GROUP BY EMPID

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Modify Where Condition with your date range